# Use v-model with a checkbox when v-for is used with properties of an object

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Using `v-model` with a checkbox works **when `v-for` is used with an array of objects**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    names: [
      { name: 'jack', checked: true },
      { name: 'john', checked: false },
      { name: 'mike', checked: false }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='example'>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in names" :key="index">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="item.name" v-model="item.checked">
  <label :for="item.name">{{ item.name }} {{ item.checked }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `v-model` with a checkbox doesn't work **when `v-for` is used with properties of an object**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    names: {
      jack: true,
      john: false,
      mike: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='example'>
  Does not work with v-for:
  <div v-for="(value, key, index) in names" :key="index">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="key" v-model="value">
  <label :for="key">{{ key }} {{ value }}</label>
  </div>
  But it does work without v-for:
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" v-model="names.jack">
  <label for="jack">jack</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" v-model="names.john">
  <label for="john">john</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" v-model="names.mike">
  <label for="mike">mike</label>
  <br>
  And it even changes the checkbox above!
</div>
```

But using `v-model` with a checkbox works **with properties of an object without `v-for`**!

Why is that? How can I fix it? I really need `v-for` to **work with properties of an object**!

EDIT: I don't need an array of checked values, I need to change the exact values of the properties of the object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The syntax `v-model="names[key]"` will work, see [Dynamic v-model directive](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1056#issuecomment-122332534)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    names: {
      jack: true,
      john: false,
      mike: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='example'>
  Does not work with v-for:
  <div v-for="(value, key, index) in names" :key="index">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="key" v-model="names[key]">
    <label :for="key">{{ key }} {{ value }}</label>
  </div>
  But it does work without v-for:
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" v-model="names.jack">
  <label for="jack">jack</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" v-model="names.john">
  <label for="john">john</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" v-model="names.mike">
  <label for="mike">mike</label>
  <br>
  And it even changes the checkbox above!
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, i spent the entire evening working on this... i don't know why i missed this syntax in the documentation...

Comment: God I hate Javascript.